# ImageMagick getting uncaught Fatal error after doing 5-7 sets of PDF to JPG

Tags: php, imagemagick, ubuntu-12.04, ghostscript, imagick

I'm on as following

```
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.18 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)
ImageMagick 6.6.9-7
GPL Ghostscript 9.05 (2012-02-08)
```

my gs is under `/usr/bin`

I'm converting continuously - PDF to JPG each pdf page to single image. It worked first time for 1-30 sets of PDF but now I'm getting error after 7 sets of PDF being complete

running the PHP script in command line. After converting 5-7 sets of PDF to JPG separate images (about 1000 JPG) i'm getting the following error

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Postscript delegate failed `../books/58/58.pdf': @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/663' in /var/www/mysite/public_html/admin/lib.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/mysite/public_html/admin/lib.php(10): Imagick->__construct('../books/58/58....')
#1 /var/www/mysite/public_html/admin/test.php(118): include('/var/www/stagin...')
#2 {main}
thrown in /var/www/mysite/public_html/admin/lib.php on line 10
```

lib.php has the script to convert the PDF to JPG - code as below

```
<?php
$file_name = "../books/$book_id/$book_id".'.pdf';
mkdir("../books/$book_id/pages");

// Strip document extension
$file_name = basename($file_name, '.pdf');

// Convert this document
// Each page to single image
$img = new imagick("../books/$book_id/$book_id".'.pdf');

// Set image resolution
// Determine num of pages
$img->setResolution(300,300);
$num_pages = $img->getNumberImages();

// Convert PDF pages to images
for($i = 0;$i < $num_pages; $i++) {
// Set iterator postion
$img->setIteratorIndex($i);
// Set image format
$img->setImageFormat('jpeg');
// Write Images to temp 'upload' folder
$img->writeImage("../books/$book_id/pages/$i".'.jpg');
}
$img->destroy();

?>
```

After getting the error it stop the converting, but when I run the script again it works for another 5-7 sets of PDF and stop again.
Can anyone please tell me what i'm missing here.

I appreciate your kind help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your ghostscript and ImageMagick are pretty out of date, and these things are always improving - maybe you could update your software and see if that helps...

Comment: Try using Ghostscript directly if all you want is a JPEG of each page of a PDF file. That way if you get an error you'll be able to tell us what it says, and you can open a GS bug report. Unless you plan to process the images after you've rendered them you don't need ImageMagick, GS can do the work alone.

Answer (score 0):

As @KenS suggested, this is probably a case where calling GhostScript directly would be better, as it would be both faster, and not crash.

I would suspect that the issue that you're seeing is that some resource is being held open by ImageMagick, and that at some point the processing just starts failing because there is no more of that resource available.

If you wanted to investigate that, [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) would be the tool to do it with. However just calling GS directly would allow you to get on to more important stuff.